# pyspark replace abbrevations from a text column

Tags: python, regex, pyspark

My spark version is as follow

```
sc.version
'2.3.0.2.6.5.223-1'
```

I have data below and want to replace all abbreviations such as won't, aren't (ones that contain '). I figured out how to find rows that have '

```
data = [{"Category": "I've never had somebody [redacted-number] [redacted-number] [redacted-number] not.", "ID": 1, "Value": 121.44, "Truth": True},
        {"Category": '<unk> [redacted-number] [redacted-number] [redacted-number].', "ID": 2, "Value": 300.01, "Truth": False},
        {"Category": '<unk> [redacted-number] [redacted-number],', "ID": 2, "Value": 300.01, "Truth": False},
        {"Category": "A phone USAA my name won't is. ", "ID": 3, "Value": 10.99, "Truth": None},
        {"Category": '[noise]. ', "ID": 4, "Value": 33.87, "Truth": True},
        {"Category": '[noise]?', "ID": 4, "Value": 33.87, "Truth": True}
        ]
dfspark = sc.createDataFrame(data)
dfspark.show(6,False)

+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---+-----+------+
|Category                                                                          |ID |Truth|Value |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---+-----+------+
|I've never had somebody [redacted-number] [redacted-number] [redacted-number] not.|1  |true |121.44|
|<unk> [redacted-number] [redacted-number] [redacted-number].                      |2  |false|300.01|
|<unk> [redacted-number] [redacted-number],                                        |2  |false|300.01|
|A phone USAA my name won't is.                                                    |3  |null |10.99 |
|[noise].                                                                          |4  |true |33.87 |
|[noise]?                                                                          |4  |true |33.87 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---+-----+------+

abbrevations_dictionary={"I've":"I have", "won't": "will not"}
abbrevations_dictionary

{"I've": 'I have', "won't": 'will not'}

dfspark.filter(dfspark.Category.contains("'")).select('Category').show(5,False)#false shows entire content

+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Category                                                                          |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|I've never had somebody [redacted-number] [redacted-number] [redacted-number] not.|
|A phone USAA my name won't is.                                                    |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Things I want to accomplish are:

1. how to find all words that have ' in them? I need all those words so that I can populate keys of the dictionary `abbrevations_dictionary`
2. Once we find all that have ' then how to replace those using the dictionary  `abbrevations_dictionary`. I would like keep rest of the the same. For example `A phone USAA my name won't is.`    should change to `A phone USAA my name will not is.`

Comment: take a look at this function? 
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_extract.html

Answer (score 1):

**For Spark version >= 3.1.0**
You can extract all instances of phrases containing ' with the following code:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ("I've never had somebody couldn't [redacted-number] [redacted-number] [redacted-number] not.",),
    ("A phone USAA my name won't is.",)
], ['Category'])

df = (
    df
    .withColumn('regexp_extract', f.expr("""regexp_extract_all(Category, "(?:^| )([a-zA-Z]+'[a-zA-Z]+)(?: |$|\.)")"""))
)

df.show()

+--------------------+----------------+
|            Category|  regexp_extract|
+--------------------+----------------+
|I've never had so...|[I've, couldn't]|
|A phone USAA my n...|         [won't]|
+--------------------+----------------+
```

Once you've constructed your the dictionary of changes that you wanna make:

```
dictionary_of_changes = {
    "I've": "I have",
    "couldn't": "could not",
    "won't": "will not"
}

df = (df
      .withColumn('dictionary_of_changes', f.map_from_arrays(f.array(*[f.lit(key) for key in dictionary_of_changes.keys()]), f.array(*[f.lit(value) for value in dictionary_of_changes.values()])))
      .withColumn('CategoryRefined', f.expr('aggregate(regexp_extract, Category, (final_string, element) -> regexp_replace(final_string, element, element_at(dictionary_of_changes, element)))'))
     )
```

and the output will be:
[image]

Comment: which functions are you exporting? I get an error - `NameError: name 'f' is not defined
`

Comment: I'm importing pyspark.sql.functions as f. ```import pyspark.sql.functions as f```

Comment: getting error `AnalysisException: "Undefined function: 'regexp_extract_all'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.; line 1 pos 0"`

Comment: which version of spark sql are you using? This transformation is available after version 3.1.0. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#regexp_extract_all

Comment: `'2.3.0.2.6.5.223-1'` and i cannot update it to the latest version

Comment: That's too old for me. The ```aggregate``` built-in function has been available since version 2.4.0, so even if we fix the issue with ```regexp_extract_all```, we're gonna have a problem with ```aggregate```. BTW, Spark updates are backward compatible, so everything will still work if you update your version of spark

Comment: oh ...sad to hear that. Could you fix `regexp_extract_all` for time being? will worry about `aggregate` later  - Also in mean time could you answer `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72379119/spark-python-understanding-regex-usage`...thanks